# Adding absolutely positioned captions to slideshow- jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

I am helping a company move some Flash slideshows and maps to jQuery presentations that will work on all platforms.

Previous dev used jqBanner plugin to provide captions over a semitransparent layer on bottom of show and was fired for this transgression.  The original Flash had those captions positioned in **various locations** depending on the photo.

My question is whether there is either a jQuery plugin that supports positioned captions in **multiple locations** or which would be a good starting point for modifications?  To reiterate- What I am hoping to find is a slideshow that makes it easy to specify positioning for each caption separately and in time with the slideshow shifts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the container of the images/content a position of "relative" and when appending/adding the layover to that container and giving it a position of absolute, you can position it anywhere but the initial constraints will be based on the parent elements positioning

```
<div style="position:realitive" id="main_wrap">
   <img src="img.jpg">
   <div style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:50px;z-index:10;">Text</div>
</div>
```

for a quick example... course since your doing it slide show style, i'd replace the image with a unordered list, where each child in the list contains the image you want, then I'd rotate through those similar to this method I helped someone out with earlier http://jsfiddle.net/BsREB/

then with jQuery, javascript, whatever, you can dynamicaly change the layover text and position according to your desire..

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm familiar with how to use CSS to position elements.  What I am hoping to find is a slideshow that makes it easy to specify positioning for each caption separately and in time with the slideshow shifts.

Comment: with a little configuration of the jsfiddle I linked to, on every transition you could apply a new position to the layover and change the text. I currently dont know of any existing plugins that do exactly what you want, almost all of what your gonna find will likely require some form of teawking or another. Mine may not be an absolute answer, but its the most core form of one making it easy to add to for the needs of any given thing per say.. who knows, I have been meaning to create some stuff to release, maybe ill start with a slide show with options like you seek.

Comment: I guess I see your point.  That would not be a bad starting place. I'd like to start with a working slideshow but perhaps I could just add the captions to run parallel.